# El servidor me cierra conexion con el servidor mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas, tengo una aplicacion hecha en java y mysql, al cabo de las horas se cierra la conexion, entiendo que por la variable global del servidor mysql wait-timeout.

Tengo una clase que me crea la conexion a la BBDD y luego una clase "gestora" donde hago todas las consultas y updates. Creo que el problema viene en que no cierro la conexion y al quedarse abierta, una vez se cumple el timeout de mysql, se corta...

La cosa es que he intentado crear una conexion en cada metodo y cerrarla pero al cerrarla y volver a hacer una conexion me da el error de no operations allowed after connection closed.

Mi clase para crear la conexion es

```
public class SGBD {
private static Connection conn=null;
public static SGBD instance;
private String servidor;
private String IP;
private String user;
private String password;

private SGBD(String servidor, String IP,String user, String password){

    this.setServidor(servidor);
    this.setIP(IP);
    this.setUser(user);
    this.setPassword(password);

    try{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Driver no encontrado");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:"+this.getServidor()+"://"+this.getIP(),this.getUser(),this.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Conexion establecida con exito.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error en la conexion, el mensaje es: "+e.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }

}
public static boolean isConnected(){
    return !(conn==null);
}
public Connection getConn() {
    return conn;
}
public static SGBD getInstance(String servidor, String IP,String user, String password){
    if(isConnected()){
        return instance;
        }else{
            instance=new SGBD(servidor,IP,user,password);
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Y la clase que genera consultas es parecido a esto:

```
public class GestorBD {

Connection conn;

/**
 * Constructor de la clase
 * @param servidor
 * @param ip
 * @param username
 * @param password
 */
public GestorBD(String servidor, String ip, String username, String password){
    this.setConn(SGBD.getInstance(servidor, ip, username, password).getConn());
}
public GestorBD(){
    //Base de datos servidor remoto
    this.setConn(SGBD.getInstance("","","","").getConn());
    //Base de datos servidor local
    //this.setConn(SGBD.getInstance("","","","").getConn());
}

public Connection getConn(){
    return conn;    
}

public void setConn(Connection conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}


/**
 * Obtener la lista de las inmobiliarias registradas en la BBDD
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws EmailIncorrectoException 
 * @throws LongitudCadenaException 
 */
public List <Inmobiliaria> getInmobiliarias() throws SQLException, LongitudCadenaException, EmailIncorrectoException{
    List <Inmobiliaria> lista = new ArrayList<Inmobiliaria>();
    this.getConn().createStatement().execute("USE `mhs_simple_form`");
    Statement stm = this.getConn().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from tbl_inmobiliaria ORDER BY nombre_inmobiliaria ASC");

    while(rs.next()){
        Inmobiliaria inmo = new Inmobiliaria(
                rs.getInt("id_inmobiliaria"),
                rs.getString("nombre_inmobiliaria"), 
                rs.getString("email_inmobiliaria"), 
                rs.getString("pass_inmobiliaria"), 
                rs.getString("telefono_inmobiliaria"), 
                rs.getInt("estado_inmobiliaria"));
        lista.add(inmo);
    }
    stm.close();
    rs.close();
    return lista;
}
```

No se bien donde cerrar la conexion puesto que me da error. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Podrías indicar que caractrísticas tiene tu aplicación. ¿Es una aplicación de consola, una web o un aplicación de escritorio? Si es web, sobre que está corriendo (Tomcat, Jetty, etc).

Comment: Es una aplicacion web que esta corriendo en tomcat 7 en vps plesk con ubuntu. Gracias

Comment: Cómo te ha ido? Has podido configurar el pool de conexiones?

Comment: Si, he puesto mi solucion mas abajo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta a tu consulta, deberías volver a abrirla si detectas que se ha cerrado (deberías cambiar tu código para verificar esto).

Ahora, bien en un entorno web de java suele ser recomendable dejar el manejo de las conexiones al `servlet container` (como lo es `Tomcat`) o al `application server` mediante un pool de conexiones.

Esto te libera de gestionar las conexiones, es decir, crear conexiones, cerrarlas y volverlas a abrir en caso de ser necesario.

Te sugiero mirar en detalle algún tutorial como [este](http://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/05/como-crear-un-pool-de-conexiones-en-tomcat.html) y [este otro](http://www.psep.cl/2013/03/17/pool-de-conexiones-con-tomcat/). Y leer la documentación de Tomcat sobre [JDBC connections](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

Si surge algún problema, pasate por SO-es y vemos como te ayudamos.

Comment: Pues voy a hacerlo mediante un pool de conexiones y os comento a ver que tal. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, pues ya esta solucionado. Con el pool de conexiones tal y como me habíais comentado he conseguido que todo funcione perfectamente sin la necesidad de complicarme mucho con las conexiones!

El problema estaba en la conexión declarada como estática, siempre había la misma y al pasar el tiempo de inactividad mysql la cortaba...

Por si a alguien le sirve pongo parte del código

El pool

```
public class Pool {

public BasicDataSource basicDataSource;

public String db = "db";
public String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + db;
public String user = "user";
public String pass = "pass";

public Pool(){
    inicializeDataSource();
}

private void inicializeDataSource(){
    basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUsername(user);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(pass);
    basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
    basicDataSource.setMaxActive(150);

}
```

Y la clase para hacer querys y updates

```
public class GestorPoolBD {

private DataSource dataSource=null;

public GestorPoolBD(){
    dataSource = new Pool().basicDataSource;
}

/** Getters setters DataSource */
public void setDataSource (DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
public DataSource getDataSourcer(){
   return dataSource;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Obtener la lista de las inmobiliarias registradas en la BBDD
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws EmailIncorrectoException 
 * @throws LongitudCadenaException 
 */
public List <Inmobiliaria> getInmobiliarias(){

    Connection conn = null;
    List <Inmobiliaria> lista = new ArrayList<Inmobiliaria>();
    try{
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.createStatement().execute("USE `db`");
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from tbl_inmobiliaria ORDER BY nombre_inmobiliaria ASC");

        while(rs.next()){
            Inmobiliaria inmo = new Inmobiliaria(
                    rs.getInt("id_inmobiliaria"),
                    rs.getString("nombre_inmobiliaria"), 
                    rs.getString("email_inmobiliaria"), 
                    rs.getString("pass_inmobiliaria"), 
                    rs.getString("telefono_inmobiliaria"), 
                    rs.getInt("estado_inmobiliaria"));
            lista.add(inmo);
        }
        stm.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LongitudCadenaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EmailIncorrectoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error cerrando la conexion");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Falta capturar bien posibles errores pero he comprobado que la conexiones no se quedan abiertas y luego mueren

Muchas gracias por las sugerencias!

Comment: Si está ha sido la solución a tu problema, entonces deberías aceptarla como respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Claro que ha sido la solucion

Answer (score -1):

> al cabo de las horas se cierra la conexion

Exactamente, se puede definir un valor en el cual si no se registran operaciones, la conexion se cierra.

Cuando obtienes este mensaje es porque simplemente no puedes acceder a los datos dentro de la Base de datos simplemente por lo que comentas, la conexion esta cerrada.

> no operations allowed after connection closed.